# How to SED on next line value

Tags: linux

May I ask for your assistance, I have a file that I need to change the next value using sed, on the example below, the idea is to change the value 99 to 90 after the line  only, so the the other value 99  should still remain 99

```
<param name="example01">
  <value>99</value>
</param>

<param name="example02">
  <value>99</value>
</param>
```

Please need you help, and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If "the line only" is the first line, then this should work. It looks for a line that contains "example01" then goes to the line after it and changes 99 to 90. Of course it does this for all lines that contain "example01"

```
    /example01/ {
    n
    s/99/90/
    }
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your response, is this is how to execute it:

Comment: sed '/example01/{n s/99/90}' filename

Comment: Im really sorry im not so hardcore linux

Comment: What I do is to put the sed script in a file such as "a.sed" then, assuming your file is "a.file", the command would look like "sed -f a.sed a.file"

Comment: hmm...im really sorry for being such annoying, but what I want to do is: I have a file name user.xml file and inside that file I need to change "99" to "90" after the line "example01", my problem is there is also another value "99" after the line "example02" that I do not what to be affected or changed.

Comment: I tried what you said I put into a script file but still it doesnt work, any other ideas? please, I can no longer think of other options, thank you very much for your time and effort

Comment: That's ok, I was a beginner once too. What does the output look like. The sed file specifically looks for "example01" and only changes 99 to 90 on the following line. Since the second one has "example02" it will not match so the following line is not changed. I don't know much about formatting on this site; all the lines in the sed file should start at the left, not indented as shown above I believe the sed file needs to keep the commands on separate lines too.

Comment: Hi sorry for my late reply I was off for a while, but anyways I did what you said, I put script you said into a file and run sed -f scriptfile file

Comment: what happened is it shows the whole content of the file but nothing has changed

Comment: (sorry about the formatting) I tried again and still got this:sed -f a.sed file.txt
    <param name="example01">
      <value>90</value>
    </param>

    <param name="example02">
      <value>99</value>
    </param>

Comment: I made this into a file:

Comment: I created a file and name it as "sedfile" put what you said: /swirec/ {
    n
    s/90/80/
    }
then execute it sed -f sedfile test, and this is the error I got: sh: cho: command not found